# Can JQPlot draggable chart be dragged quantitatively?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am drawing a JQplot chart, there are two lines in the chart, one is fixed, one is draggable, like the chart showed below[image]

My question is, can the yellow draggable line be dragged more quantitatively/smart? For example, if I only drag one point like the image showed, all the points followed it will be dragged with the same scale as the first one at the same time. Is that possible for JQPlot? The reason why I wanna implement it is because there are almost 80 points in the chart, it is trouble for user to drag the point one by one. It will be highly appreciated if you can help me figure it out. Thanks!

Add: I found a good example for my case like the [link(Trefis Forecast Tool)](http://www.trefis.com/company?homeFeatured=TWX#/TWX/n-2062?from=sankey) showed. So, is it possible for JQPlot? Thanks!

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know the answer to your question. Why I'm commenting: jqPlot is not supported any longer (from what I can tell), and there is [a much better alternative called flot.](http://www.flotcharts.org/)